# apt-get error phpldapadmin

Tags: server, apt, apache2, php

want to update the apache on a ubuntu 12.04 with this manual:
https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2014/07/17/upgrading-apache-http-server-2-2-to-2-4-on-ubuntu-12-04/

I uninstalled apache2.2 and now I want to install apache 2.4 but wenn I want to install it I got the message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

php5-cli : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 is to be installed

php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 is to be installed

php5-gd : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 is to be installed

php5-sqlite : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 is to be installed

php5-tidy : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 is to be installed

php5-xmlrpc : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 is to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

With "apt-get -f install" I got:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing phpldapadmin (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpldapadmin
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I dont need phpldapadmin. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you still have some PHP packages installed with version `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6`, while the new package is trying to install `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26`. These versions mismatch. Try uninstalling the old PHP packages first:

```
apt-get remove php5-cli php5-curl php5-gd php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-common phpldapadmin
```

There might be other PHP packages left, so you might also want to use the wildcard:

```
apt-get remove php5-* phpldapadmin
```

After the packages have been removed, reinstall everything with the new version:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-cli php5-curl php5-gd php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-common apache2
```